# C# UIAutomation and VB ListView20WndClass

Tags: vb6, ui-automation

Does anyone know of any Pattern I can use in order to iterate through a VB6 ListView? Ive run through what I see as available but keep getting errors.

Comment: "Ive run through what I see as available..." Show some code. "...but keep getting errors." Would be more helpful if you actually  showed what error(s) you are getting.

Comment: question assumes the person who comments has used the package listed.

Answer (score 1):

No patterns for VB6Listview to UIAutomationElement are available.